# Declared a self referential struct in 'header.h' file and trying to define it in 'main.c' and this causes error

Tags: c, variables, linker-errors, extern

**"main.c"**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    int ch;
    start = NULL;
    printf("Enter your choice:\n");
    printf("1 --> To create list\n");

    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
        start = create(start);
        break;
    }
}
```

**"header.h"**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node NODE;

struct node
{
int info;
NODE* link;
};

extern NODE *start;

NODE* create(NODE*);
```

- The error is undefined reference to 'start' in main, but i have already declared it the header file, and i have even included 'header.h' file in 'main.c' file.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is including the correct `header.h`?  Can you write: `NODE *alter_ego = NULL;` in `main()` before you assign to `start`?  If not, you've probably managed to include the wrong `header.h` despite your best intentions.

Comment: Are you getting this error when compiling or linking?

Comment: @FredMiller: Good catch — "undefined reference" is normally a linker error, and since `main.c` doesn't define `start`, unless there's another object file that does define it, the reported error message is inevitable.  That's much more probable than my 'wrong header' suggestion.

Comment: In C a "declaration" is just a promise to the compiler that the thingy mentioned would be "defined" somewhere else, and be found by the linker on link-time, if the latter fails, the linker  complains about an "undefined reference".

Answer (score 4):

in `header.h` you have **declared** `extern NODE *start`

But the **definition** of `start` is not given.

You need to **define** `start`. Usually in some `.c` file.  Probably in `main.c`.

```
NODE *start;   //in Global space, above main() function.
```

Also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files/1433387#1433387) for further information.